# To get accesstoken from microsoft outlook graph api for daemon app

Tags: python, email, daemon, outlook-restapi

I am trying to create a daemon python application which will get emails from outlook server using Microsoft outlook graph API. They have provided excellent tutorial and documentation on how to get it done for python app like django and flask. But I want to create daemon script which can get access code without using web interface(which was used in django).

Note: This app will only collect email from single email and will feed it to db.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what kind of security you need. You can have your daemon/service authenticate with username/password directly, or you can have it authenticate with a certificate.

There are several different authentication scenarios, take a look at the [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api).

Either way, you need to register your daemon as an app in Azure and give it permissions to the Outlook API, just as if it were a web app.

Comment: I have already registered with Azure Active directory and want to authenticate with username/password basis. What is the next step should I take.

Comment: It may be that username/password auth is not possible in python. Vittorio writes in this 2014 blog post, that they only implemented it for .NET (http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/). In .NET you can create a ``UserCredential`` with username and passowrd. That is then passed to the ``AcquireTokenAsync`` method. Sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/blob/master/TodoListClient/Program.cs#L159